# Run a defined function for various variables in R

Tags: r, function

I have defined a function for descriptive statistics, which is

```
descriptive_statistics<-function(obj){
  n<-length(obj)
  cat("mean=" ,mean(obj) , "\n")
  cat("s.d.=",sd(obj),"\n")
  cat("min=" ,min(obj ) , "\n")
  cat("1. Quartil=" ,quantile(obj, 0.25) , "\n")
  cat("median=",median(obj),"\n")
  cat("3. Quartil=" ,quantile(obj, 0.75) , "\n")  
  cat ( "max= " , max (obj ) , "\n" )  
    skew<-(sum((obj-mean(obj))^3)/n)/(sum((obj-mean(obj))^2)/n)^(3/2)
  cat("skewness=",skew,"\n")
  kurt<-n*sum((obj-mean(obj))^4)/(sum((obj-mean(obj))^2)^2)
  cat("kurtosis=",kurt,"\n")
  Stat<-n*skew^2/6+n*(kurt - 3)^2/24
}
```

For any variable that I put in the command, it gives me this output:

```
descriptive_statistics(data$ewz_2016)
mean= 232024.4 
s.d.= 383172 
min= 36514 
1. Quartil= 81632 
median= 121705 
3. Quartil= 230405.5 
max= 3516100 
skewness= 5.930454 
kurtosis= 46.42959
```

My wish would be to put various variables in the command at the same time (e.g. the variables from the columns 3-25) and afterwards copy the table to Excel to format it.
Does anyone have a piece of advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the function `descriptive_statistics` to return the values it computes in the form of a *named vector*. In what follows the function doesn't print anything, it just computes those values. You can combine the two, yours and this version of it, if you want.

```
descriptive_statistics2 <- function(obj){
  n <- length(obj)
  skew<-(sum((obj-mean(obj))^3)/n)/(sum((obj-mean(obj))^2)/n)^(3/2)
  kurt <- n*sum((obj-mean(obj))^4)/(sum((obj-mean(obj))^2)^2)
  Stat <- n*skew^2/6+n*(kurt - 3)^2/24
  c(mean = mean(obj),
    s.d. = sd(obj),
    min = min(obj),
    Quartil = quantile(obj, 0.25),  # Note: no need to say it's quartile 1 or 3
    median = median(obj),
    Quartil = quantile(obj, 0.75),  # quantile() will append a 25% or 75%
    max = max(obj),
    skewness = skew,
    kurtosis = kurt,
    Stat = Stat
  )
}
```

Now test it with some data.

```
set.seed(8085)  # make it reproducible
n <- 1e2
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(25*n), ncol = 25))

result <- t(sapply(dat[3:25], descriptive_statistics2))
head(result)
#          mean      s.d.       min Quartil.25%      median Quartil.75%      max
#V3  0.04496632 0.9454383 -2.114690  -0.6352870  0.13869333   0.6789609 1.901803
#V4  0.08136469 1.0594723 -1.955842  -0.6922518 -0.03305246   0.8274921 2.653876
#V5 -0.05899082 1.0225392 -3.031083  -0.6536158 -0.16813752   0.6497042 2.053943
#V6  0.13282456 0.9746959 -1.715005  -0.5399552  0.05815323   0.8383848 2.308354
#V7  0.03935582 1.1629889 -2.669025  -0.6569735 -0.01753087   0.6976987 3.277311
#V8 -0.08203328 1.1111241 -2.755361  -0.9619138 -0.08806534   0.8730580 2.547580
#      skewness kurtosis      Stat
#V3 -0.20061108 2.414033 2.1014041
#V4  0.32427896 2.455259 2.9890412
#V5 -0.21501670 2.758610 1.0133248
#V6  0.16328790 2.322679 2.3558991
#V7  0.09352129 2.977775 0.1478287
#V8 -0.05664655 2.509671 1.0552417
```

Finally, to export the result to Excel, use `write.csv`, if your country uses the period as decimal point or `write.csv2` if it uses the comma.

```
write.csv(result, file = "SCW16.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```